Tu B’Av as the Start of the Grape Harvest
I frequently see references on the internet to Tu B’Av marking the start of the grape harvest.
One example from Jewish Virtual Library is below. [1]
My question is, what is the source for this?
Is it simply assumed from Ta’anit 26b’s reference to “dancing in the vineyards”?
[1] https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/tu-b-rsquo-av

That seems a bit odd, as the spies began their trip to Israel "when the grapes were ripening", and came back 40 days later, with grapes, on the 9th of Av.

Hmm, first I heard of the notion was last week when one of my uni professors told us that Tu b'Av had likely been a grape harvest festival for two reason: it was the right time and it featured dancing in vineyards.

Yosef was released from prison 2 years after the chief butler and it was around Rosh Hashanah, The Chief butler was squeezing ripened grapes into the pharaoh's cup. Grapes ripen within 30-70 days depending on spieces. That's quite within Tu b'Av.
